# Introduce NA in a value text exist into two columns

Tags: r, regex

Having a df like this:

```
df_in <- data.frame(x = c('x1','x2','x3','x4'),
                    col1 = c('http://youtube.com/something','NA','https://www.yahooexample.com','https://www.yahooexample2.com'),
                    col2 = c('www.youtube.com/searcht', 'http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321','NA','https://google.com/text'))
```

What kind of grep should I implement in order to check col1 and col2 and if "youtube" phrase exist in both columns in the same row replace it with NA.

Example of expected output

```
> df_in <- data.frame(x = c('x1','x2','x3','x4'),
+                     col1 = c('NA','NA','https://www.yahooexample.com','https://www.yahooexample2.com'),
+                     col2 = c('NA', 'http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321','NA','https://google.com/text'))
> df_in
   x                          col1                           col2
1 x1                            NA                             NA
2 x2                            NA http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321
3 x3  https://www.yahooexample.com                             NA
4 x4 https://www.yahooexample2.com        https://google.com/text
```

Comment: Just `df_in[sapply(df_in, grepl, pattern = 'youtube')] <- NA`?

Comment: @Jaap thank but it is the same as the answer it removes also the one which only be in one of two columns. I want to exist in both columns

Comment: Why do you use `'NA'` instead of a real `NA`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to use `rowSums` with `sapply` and `grepl`:

```
df_in[rowSums(sapply(df_in, grepl, pattern = 'youtube')) > 1, 2:3] <- 'NA'
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df_in
>    x                          col1                           col2
> 1 x1                            NA                             NA
> 2 x2                            NA http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321
> 3 x3  https://www.yahooexample.com                             NA
> 4 x4 https://www.yahooexample2.com        https://google.com/text
> ```

Answer (score 3):

you can try a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_in %>% 
  unite(a,starts_with("col")) %>% 
  mutate(a=ifelse(str_count(a,"youtube")>1, "NA_NA", a)) %>% 
  separate(a, c("col1","col2"), "_")
   x                          col1                           col2
1 x1                            NA                             NA
2 x2                            NA http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321
3 x3  https://www.yahooexample.com                             NA
4 x4 https://www.yahooexample2.com        https://google.com/text
```

In base R I would do:

```
df_out <- df_in
df_out[,-1] <-  t(apply(df_in[,-1], 1, function(x){
      tmp <- grepl("youtube",x[1]) + grepl("youtube",x[2])
      if(tmp > 1) rep("NA",2) else x

  }
    ))
df_out  
   x                          col1                           col2
1 x1                            NA                             NA
2 x2                            NA http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321
3 x3  https://www.yahooexample.com                             NA
4 x4 https://www.yahooexample2.com        https://google.com/text
```

The idea is to count the occurrence of `"youtube"`. If there are `n=2` per row, replace the entries with `NA` otherwise leave them as they are.

Comment: That'll change all instances of "youtube" rather than just those that appear in both columns.

Answer (score 1):

Not an improvement on @Jaap's answer, but an alternative:

```
df_in[do.call(`&`,lapply(df_in[,2:3], grepl, pattern = "youtube")), 2:3] <- 'NA'
```